# How to run code if certain message was sent (Telegram Bot)

Tags: c#, bots, telegram-bot

I am creating a simple Telegram Bot that sends weather information depending on geolocation.

I want it to work like this:

1. User types /weather in chat
2. Bot says that geolocation is mandatory and the custom keyboard requesting location appears
3. User presses the button to share location and gets a result (weather info)

Everything is fine except one thing - if user sends his location manually, bot reacts to it and gives feedback about weather. I would like to make it (weather info code) work only when /weather was sent in chat. I had an idea to check whether previous message text equals to "/weather" but could not find the solution. :/

### C# Code:

```
private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = e.Message;

        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text) return;

        try
        {
            switch (message.Text)
            {
                case "/weather":
                    var requestLocationKeyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new[]
                        {
                                new KeyboardButton("Share my location") {RequestLocation = true},
                            });

                    Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
                       message.Chat.Id,
                       "To get the information about weather, you should share your current location.",
                       replyMarkup: requestLocationKeyboard);
                    break;



private static async void Bot_OnLocationReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var message = e.Message;
        if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Location) return;

        var latitude = message.Location.Latitude;
        var longitude = message.Location.Longitude;

        latitude = (float)Math.Round(latitude, 3);
        longitude = (float)Math.Round(longitude, 3);

        Lat = latitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Lon = longitude.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(
            message.Chat.Id,
            "_Processing Received Location..._",
            ParseMode.Markdown,
            replyMarkup: new ReplyKeyboardRemove());

        Console.WriteLine("{0};{1}", Lat, Lon);

        WeatherResponse weather = GetWeatherData();
        await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, "Your location: " + weather.List[0].Name + "\n" +
                                                        "Temperature: " + Convert.ToInt32(weather.List[0].Main.Temp) + " °C" +
                                                        "\n" + "Summary: " + weather.List[0].Weather[0].Description);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class field to store the last message

```
private string _lastMessage;

private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    var message = e.Message;

    if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.Text) return;

    _lastMessage = message.Text; // <=============
    try
    {
        switch (message.Text)
    ...
}
```

In `Bot_OnLocationReceived`:

```
if (_lastMessage  == "/weather") {
    //TODO: display weather info
} else {
    //TODO: display only geo location.
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much for your attention and reply. It worked fine but also I added a bool _isLocationReceived and add it into the if-statement you suggested. And now it works perfectly :) Thanks again